# How can I check if Subversion 1.6 has compression turned on?

Tags: svn

I am using Subversion 1.6. How can I check if compression is turned on? I cannot find any reference anywhere. There is some reverence to 1.7 and compression, especially that one can adjust the compression rate, but nothing says that compression in itself is a fully new feature for 1.7.

Thanks

Comment: What compression and where? Too vague.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to data caching compression the feature was added on 1.7, you can see it being discussed on the [1.7 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#server-performance-tuning).  Prior to that - 1.6 in your case - there was no compression capability.